# In an agentivity hierarchy, where do plurals fit in?

Tags: plurality, agentivity

In a language with such a system, nouns and pronouns are ranked based on how likely they are to be agents. I've seen it said in multiple places that typically first and second person appear on top (which is higher than the other varies from language to language), followed by third persons in decreasing rank of agentivity.

However, I've never seen it mentioned how number plays into this. Is first person plural considered higher agency than third person? What about third person plurals? Do they rank higher or lower than single persons? Does number trump person or is it the other way around? What about nouns? Is a plural noun higher agency than a singular one?

Checking word frequency for English, I found these are the English pronouns that appear the most (in descending order):

I
He
You
It
They
She
We

Don't know about agentivity, since this list only finds frequency. It does however seem to rank plural pronouns below singular. The first two are singular, the third can either be plural or singular, and in the case of English it also doubles as the object form, making it surely appear more frequently. The fourth and sixth are singular, while the fifth and final ones are plural. Sadly, outside of 'you', no object pronouns appear in the top 100 words. Could this be an indicator that plural pronouns have lower agency than singular ones regardless of person (and yes I see that she ranks below 'they', and two ranks below 'it', wtf?)

edit: Remembered that The Construction Kit 2 has an entire verb chart showing the polypersonal endings for Nishnaabemwin, so I counted the number of 'direct' affixes among the charts for singular and plural subjects. Singular subjects had 9, plural subjects had 6. It should also be noted that the plural subjects have noticibly more endings, meaning these 6 comprise a smaller percentage of all verb endings. There's also the fact that none of them appear for the first or second person direct objects of either number. Guess this means that in Nishnaabemwin at least, person trumps number?

Comment: What's the source of your frequency list with those English pronouns? [This frequency list](https://frequencylist.com/) has the English personal pronouns in such an order, both subject and object ones: I you it we me they she her him us them. And [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rtatman/english-word-frequency) has them this way: I you it we us they he me them her she him.

Comment: The Conlanger's Lexipedia by Mark Rosenfelder. Its supposed to be a frequency list for fantasy novels. I don't know how much difference that would make. Also, he made the list himself using a program. I realize third persons would probably come up with more frequency in a novel, but how would you find a frequency for every-day dialogue? Base the list on movie dialogue?

Comment: I looked up agentivity and could only find that it has to do with verbs of movement. "One source of variation in descriptions of caused motion events is agentivity, which refers to the attribution of a result to the agent's action. Depending on the perspective taken, the same event may be described with agentive or non-agentive interpretations." https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/psychology/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2022.878277/full

Comment: An agentivity hierarchy is where nouns are part of a list of sorts based on how likely they are to appear as a syntactic agent (thus the name). Inanimate objects in particular are famous for rarely appearing as agents, and in fact some languages straight don't allow it! Its also common to treat things like humans and gods and other intelligent beings as having higher agency than other animates such as animals.

Comment: Most often this sort of system is used to mark subject and direct object. Essentially, as long as the subject and direct object aren't in the same tier in the hierarchy, the one higher up is assumed to be the subject. The reverse often requires special marking such as a passive voice or 'inverse' marker. Some such languages may even require all nouns in a sentence to be listed in order of animacy/agency, regardless of the role they play.

Comment: Another way this can manifest is in a split-ergative language. Nominative languages tend to like to leave the subject unmarked, while ergative languages tend to prefer to leave the direct object unmarked. In animacy-based split ergativity, nouns higher on the hierachy take nom-acc marking, but nouns lower on it take erg-abs marking instead. This is actually rather useful since this allows case marking while keeping the frequency of case markers to a minimum.

Comment: My problem is I can find no mention how plurality affects this. The common order is 1/2 person at the top, followed by third persons in decreasing animacy. Absolutely nothing though says how plurality factors into this. Are they treated the same as singular nouns? Do plurals nouns instead have lower or higher agency than singular nouns? Does person or number trump where a pronoun goes on the agentivity hierarchy? I can find NO  explanation for this anywhere.